# Why does Python 2 treat <> as valid? What does it do?

Tags: python

I was reviewing some code today and saw what I figured was a typo:

```
if foo <> bar:
    # do stuff
```

However, I'm surprised to see that Python2 appears to treat `<>` as valid:

```
% python -c 'print 1<>2'
True
```

Additionally, I can't discern what causes `<>` to return `True` vs `False`:

```
In [16]: 1 <> 2
Out[16]: True

In [17]: 2 <> 1
Out[17]: True

In [18]: 1 <> None
Out[18]: True

In [19]: 1 <> "foo"
Out[19]: True

In [20]: None <> 1
Out[20]: True

In [21]: None <> None
Out[21]: False

In [22]: False <> 1
Out[22]: True
```

One of my guesses was that Python was using both the `<` and `>` operators and I was falling victim to some boolean casting shenanigans, but that doesn't appear to be the case as `< >` isn't valid and neither is `><`:

```
In [29]: 1 >< 2
  File "<ipython-input-29-0e35e3b94016>", line 1
    1 >< 2
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

In [30]: 1 < > 2
  File "<ipython-input-30-8f2ba3fa3c6c>", line 1
    1 < > 2
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Finally, Python 3 chokes on this "operator" (or whatever it should be called):

```
% python3 -c 'print(1<>2)'
  File "<string>", line 1
    print(1<>2)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, what gives?  What is `<>` doing?  What is it?  Why is it invalid in Python 3?

Comment: @minitoto I mean, I asked this question specifically because I couldn't figure out how to google what the "<>" operator was, so I wouldn't consider that question a duplicate in that I attempted to find it and my searches failed me.  But I suppose that answer does answer my question, now that I know the answer.

Obviously I am familiar with the `!=` operator

Comment: no offense but i think it's the problem of the mass, some people just can't google or fail to and ask duplicate questions which are already have good answers

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to Google a symbol like that.

Comment: yeah, I didn't really have any luck with google or SO's search when it came to `<>`.  In retrospect I should have just ctrl-f'd on python operator docs.

Comment: Try [**SymbolHound search**](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%3C%3E+python) for stuff like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a legacy way of writing `!=`.  Don't use it in new code.  As you've already seen, it was removed in python3.x (probably because "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." and because nobody used that operator :-).

The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> The forms `<>` and `!=` are equivalent; for consistency with C, `!=` is preferred; where `!=` is mentioned below `<>` is also accepted. The `<>` spelling is **considered obsolescent**.

Comment: Yeah it's carry over from mysql where <> means Not equal.

Comment: Huh, I had focused on googling `<>` instead of just looking at Python comparison docs, so I missed that.

Comment: @UncleIroh: I always assumed it was borrowed from BASIC.

Comment: @UncleIroh any proofs on the statement?

Comment: @UncleIroh most likely it was carried over from other programming languages like BASIC

Comment: @Alik - You are probably right.  Basic is probably where Guido borrowed it from.